# how to insert values in multiple text box and updating the value in it seqentially?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**my java code**

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Revenue {
public void Execute(String value)
 {
       LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("VIEW")).click();
       LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("REVENUE")).click();
       LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.name("click")).click();
       LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'Edit_')")).click();

       List<WebElement> a = LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
       List<WebElement> b = LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value='Update']"));



       for(WebElement elem_1:a){
           elem_1.clear();            
           elem_1.sendKeys(value);
           }
       for(WebElement elem_2:b)
       {
           elem_2.click();

       }



       }


}

}
```

**my HTML**

```
<tr>
<td>Arunachal Pradesh</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_1" type="text" value="44155" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_1")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_2" type="text" value="79103" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_2")" style="width:60px"> 
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_3" type="text" value="11639" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_3")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_4" type="text" value="22004" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_4")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_5" type="text" value="65958" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_5")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
 <div>
<input id="1_6" type="text" value="76837" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_6")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_7" type="text" value="3642" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_7")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_8" type="text" value="84573" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_8")"  style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_9" type="text" value="3438" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_9")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_10" type="text" value="32859" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_10")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_11" type="text" value="45793" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_11")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_12" type="text" value="95662" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_12")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<a id="Edit_1" href="#" onclick="fnEditRevenue("1");" style="visibility: hidden;">Edit</a>
|
<a id="Hide_1" href="#" onclick="fnHideRevenue(1);" style="visibility: hidden;">Hide</a>
|
<a id="Show_1" href="#" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="fnShowRevenue(1);">Show</a>
</td>
```

Lets first understand the functionality of my application.In my webpage there are more than 26 rows and 12 column.Each row contains 12 text box and 12 buttons and a "Edit" button too.when Edit button is clicked then text box and 'update' button will be open.this is my functionality of my webpage.

And what I want to do is when Edit button is clicked then some value should enter in text box and 'update' button should be clicked.this should happens for each row.By using the above code I am able to click on single 'Edit' button and updating only single row.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: In order to be able to provide you any help, can you please paste the full HTMl of your page and provide and sample screenshot.

Comment: how can I give you the screen shoot.I edited the html code.

Comment: I uploaded the picture.

Answer (score 1):

It is updating only single row because you have not identified based on column names, try this-

```
 WebElement table = driver.findElement(By
            .cssSelector("table[id='yourtableid']"));
List<WebElement> col = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for (int cnum = 0; cnum < col.size(); cnum++) {
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
text.clear();
text.sendKeys(value);
WebElement update = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='update']"));
update.click();
}
```